# How to find an element inside a ng-repeat in protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I have the following html:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items">
    Some Test
    <span class="bubble-grey">
        {{ item }}
    </span>
</li>
```

How to find the ".bubble-grey" span inside the first ng-repeat element in protractor?

I have tried:

```
element.all(by.repeater('item in items')).get(0).findElement(by.css(".bubble-grey")).getText()
```

But I get "TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'findElement'"

Answer (score 11):

You don't need to 'find' the element again. 
Try using the element explorer

Open the element explorer and navigate to the desired page:

```
cd \node_modules\protractor\bin
node ./elementexplorer.js <your url>
```

Then try this command:

```
element.all(by.repeater('item in items')).get(0).getText()
```

I don't think it will show any text, because there is no text in the html.

If you want to get the "Some Test" text, try it:

```
element(by.repeater('item in items')).getText()
```

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the [API](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/api.md), instead of:

```
.findElement(by.css(".bubble-grey"));
```

you want:

```
.element(by.css(".bubble-grey"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Give your spans an id attribute, using the $index from the repeat, then you can jump straight to them.

```
<span class="bubble-grey" id="item_{{$index}}">
    {{ item }}
</span>
```

Comment: Yes that would be a possibility, but is it clever, to add something to (production) code, which is only necessary for testing?

Comment: You could argue that it improves your code from an accessibility side of things (e.g. screen readers etc). Unfortunately I don't know the Protractor side well enough to fix it in the test, I just know the Angular side of things.